# macOS App Crashes on 10.13 with Symbol not found: _NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am building a macOS app with Deployment Target 10.13

Works on 10.15 but crashes on 10.13

```
Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make the code that uses this variable dependent on the version of macOS that's executing:

```
if (@available(macOS 10.14, *)) {
    return NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua;
} else {
    return nil;
}
```

You can also go old-school and declare it as a weak link:

```
extern NSAppearanceName const NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua __attribute__((weak_import));
...
if (NSAppearanceNameDarkAqua!=NULL) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Makes sense; dark mode wasn't introduced until 10.14. So if you're going to run on 10.13, you mustn't load anything — not code, not asset catalog, not storyboard — that "mentions" or depends upon light/dark mode.